# PHP multisort on array field containing underscore

Tags: php, arrays, substring, delimiter, array-multisort

I have an array like this:

```
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202143_N', 'bmi' => 2.5);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202144_P', 'bmi' => 1.2);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202145_N', 'bmi' => 6.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202146_P', 'bmi' => 3.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202147_N', 'bmi' => 7.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202148_P', 'bmi' => 8.6);
```

How to sort on the ALT_ID (N to P) and bmi (low to high) to get an array like this:

```
array (
array('ALT_ID' => '202143_N', 'bmi' => 2.5),
array('ALT_ID' => '202145_N', 'bmi' => 6.6),
array('ALT_ID' => '202147_N', 'bmi' => 7.6),
array('ALT_ID' => '202144_P', 'bmi' => 1.2),
array('ALT_ID' => '202146_P', 'bmi' => 3.6),
array('ALT_ID' => '202148_P', 'bmi' => 8.6)
)
```

Here's what I have tried and its not giving the output in the desired format:

Link to the demo: https://eval.in/142639

```
<?php
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202143_N', 'bmi' => 2.5);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202144_P', 'bmi' => 1.2);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202145_N', 'bmi' => 6.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202146_P', 'bmi' => 3.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202147_N', 'bmi' => 7.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202148_P', 'bmi' => 8.6);

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $volume[$key]  = $row['ALT_ID'];
    $bmi[$key] = $row['bmi'];
}

array_multisort($volume, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $bmi, SORT_ASC, $data);

print_r($data);
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepend the last character of ALT_ID to your sort key.

```
<?php

$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202143_N', 'bmi' => 2.5);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202144_P', 'bmi' => 1.2);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202145_N', 'bmi' => 6.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202146_P', 'bmi' => 3.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202147_N', 'bmi' => 7.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202148_P', 'bmi' => 8.6);

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $pieces = explode('_',$row['ALT_ID']);
    $id_piece = $pieces[1];
    $volume[$key]  = $id_piece . $row['ALT_ID'];
    $edition[$key] = $row['bmi'];
}

//edit
array_multisort($volume, SORT_ASC, $edition, SORT_DESC, $data);

print_r($data);

?>
```

Comment: It should be `array_multisort($volume, SORT_ASC, $edition, SORT_DESC, $data);`.

Comment: But what if there are more elements after underscore?

Comment: Updated to handle more than 1 character after the underscore.

Comment: There seems to be some issue with php version 5.3.10-1 ubuntu3.10. Multisort not working with large arrays. It is working on sorting with one field though.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) would be easier:

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202143_N', 'bmi' => 2.5);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202144_P', 'bmi' => 1.2);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202145_N', 'bmi' => 6.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202146_P', 'bmi' => 3.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202147_N', 'bmi' => 7.6);
$data[] = array('ALT_ID' => '202148_P', 'bmi' => 8.6);

usort($data, function($a, $b){
$x = substr(strrchr($a['ALT_ID'], '_'), 1);
$y = substr(strrchr($b['ALT_ID'], '_'), 1);
if($x == $y) return $a['bmi']-$b['bmi'];
return strcmp($x, $y);
});

print_r($data);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/142658)